# Is YUV_420_888 format supported by the stream configurations on all devices that support Camera2 API?

Tags: android-camera2

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP) , LEGACY hardware level devices do not necessarily support YUV_420_888 as output stream configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your interpretation is incorrect. YUV_420_888 is compulsory in camera2. The table that you refer to, serves a different purpose, it sets frame size requirements. The relevant table is the first table under [CameraDevice.createCaptureSession](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.html#createCaptureSession(java.util.List<android.view.Surface>,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) (unfortunately, no exact href).

Note that YUV_420_888 is often a thin wrapper around the legacy NV21 image format.